# Update multiple rows on second table based on first table data

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have 2 tables

```
TBL_HEADER
----------
HEADER_ID
COST_CENTER


TBL_RESULTS   
-----------
WEEK_NO
COST_CENTER
HEADER_ID_FK
```

I have a requirement to copy all of the COST_CENTER_CODES from TBL_HEADER into TBL_RESULTS
joining on the HEADER_ID > HEADER_ID_FK.

I tried this but the subquery is returning multiple rows

```
  UPDATE
   TBL_RESULTS R
SET
  COST_CENTRE = (
  SELECT 
    H.COST_CENTRE
  FROM
    TBL_HEADER H,
    TBL_RESULTS R
  WHERE
    H.HEADER_ID = R.HEADER_ID_FK
  )
```

Can someone point me in the right direction and explain why this is happening?

I'm using Oracle 10.2.0.4

many thanks

JC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery, not a subquery with a join:

```
UPDATE TBL_RESULTS
SET COST_CENTRE = (SELECT H.COST_CENTRE
                   FROM TBL_HEADER H 
                   WHERE H.HEADER_ID = TBL_RESULTS.HEADER_ID_FK
                  )
```

The extra reference to `tbl_results` was causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT 
    H.COST_CENTRE
  FROM
    TBL_HEADER H,
    TBL_RESULTS R
  WHERE
    H.HEADER_ID = R.HEADER_ID_FK
```

will return every Cost Centre from TBL_HEADER where the IDs are matching. You need to "join" your subselect with your updateting statement, ie "where H.HEADER_ID = TBL_RESULTS.HEADER_ID_FK" where "TBL_RESULTS" is the table from your update statement.

Also, you don't need TBL_RESULTS R in the sub select.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
   TBL_RESULTS R
SET
  COST_CENTRE = (
  SELECT 
    H.COST_CENTRE
  FROM
    TBL_HEADER H
  WHERE
    H.HEADER_ID = R.HEADER_ID_FK
  )
```